# ThemeMode not changing when using void function in GestureDetector

Tags: android, flutter, dart, error-handling, mobile-application

I am a beginner in flutter. I am trying out my Flutter remainder app project. I got stuck in the error. when I click on the gesture detector button it should change the app bar theme as well as the scaffold theme. But it not working. Can you please help me out?

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'package:remaider_app/services/theme_services.dart';
import 'package:remaider_app/ui/home_page.dart';
import 'package:remaider_app/ui/theme.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await GetStorage.init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: Themes.light,
      darkTheme: Themes.dark,
      themeMode: ThemeServices().theme,
      home: const Homepage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Themes.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color bluishClr = Color(0xFF4e5ae8);
const Color yellowClr = Color(0xFFFFB746);
const Color pinkClr = Color(0xFFff4667);
const Color white = Colors.white;
const primaryClr = bluishClr;
const Color darkGreyClr = Color(0xFF121212);
Color darkHeaderClr = const Color(0xFF424242);

class Themes {
  static final light = ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: primaryClr),
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: white);
  static final dark = ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: darkGreyClr),
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkHeaderClr);
}
```

Services.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';

class ThemeServices {
  final _box = GetStorage();
  final _key = "isDarkMode";

  bool _loadThemeFromBox() => _box.read(_key) ?? false;

  ThemeMode get theme => _loadThemeFromBox() ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;

  void switchtheme() {
    Get.changeThemeMode(_loadThemeFromBox() ? ThemeMode.light : ThemeMode.dark);
  }
}
```

home_page.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';

class ThemeServices {
  final _box = GetStorage();
  final _key = "isDarkMode";

  bool _loadThemeFromBox() => _box.read(_key) ?? false;

  ThemeMode get theme => _loadThemeFromBox() ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;

  void switchtheme() {
    Get.changeThemeMode(_loadThemeFromBox() ? ThemeMode.light : ThemeMode.dark);
  }
}
```

I was trying to make a project or a remainder app in Flutter and I expected to get relief from the unknown error

Comment: Shouldn't you use `GetMaterialApp` if you use GetX? And as an early advice, I won't recommend using GetX as you might encounter more and more unexpected problems in the future. See this video on "Why Not GetX": https://youtu.be/zlIgy4es5Ts

Answer (score 0):

Ensure Theme Switch is Triggered:

```
void switchtheme() {
  print("Switching theme");
  Get.changeThemeMode(_loadThemeFromBox() ? ThemeMode.light : 
  ThemeMode.dark);
}
```

Update UI When Theme Changes:

```
// Example with GetBuilder
GetBuilder<ThemeServices>(
  builder: (controller) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: Themes.light,
      darkTheme: Themes.dark,
      themeMode: controller.theme, // Ensure you are using the 
      controller's theme
      home: const Homepage(),
    );
  },
);
```

Check Storage Value:

```
bool _loadThemeFromBox() {
  final isDarkMode = _box.read(_key) ?? false;
  print("Theme read from storage: $isDarkMode");
  return isDarkMode;
}
void switchtheme() {
  final isDarkMode = _loadThemeFromBox();
  print("Switching theme from $isDarkMode to ${!isDarkMode}");
  _box.write(_key, !isDarkMode);
  Get.changeThemeMode(isDarkMode ? ThemeMode.light : ThemeMode.dark);
}
```

Initialize GetStorage:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await GetStorage.init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```